# Unity: GooglePlayGames authentication and leaderboards working in local testing, but not on beta tester devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am using [GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.11.01.unitypackage](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/current-build/GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.11.01.unitypackage) to provide a leaderboard in my mobile game on Android. My game is build with Unity 2021.3.3f1. I am using the following code in my game app.

```
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;


public class GooglePlayGamesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
    }

    internal void ProcessAuthentication(SignInStatus status)
    {
        if (status == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            // Continue with Play Games Services
            Debug.Log("ProcessAuthentication success");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("ProcessAuthentication failed");
            // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a login button
            // to ask users to sign-in. Clicking it should call
            // PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ManuallyAuthenticate(ProcessAuthentication).
        }
    }
    public void ReportScore(int score)
    {
         PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ReportScore(score, GPGSIds.leaderboard_leaderboard, "some metadata", (bool success) =>
        {
            // handle success or failure
            if (success)
                Debug.Log("Submitted highscore successfully");
            else
                Debug.LogWarning("Failed to submit highscore");
        });

       
    }


    public void ShowLeaderboardUI()
    {
        Debug.Log("Trying to show Leaderboard UI now...");
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI();
    }
}
```

An external class has a reference to above GooglePlayGamesManager class. This external class calls `GooglePlayGamesManager.ShowLeaderboardUI()` and `GooglePlayGamesManager.ReportScore(score)`.

Unfortunately, for internal testers who download the beta version through the Google Play Store, ProcessAuthentication(SignInStatus status) fails, and the Google Sign in thingy never gets shown and "ProcessAuthentication failed" gets written to the log, which I am monitoring through adb logcat -s Unity.

Accordingly, ReportScore(int score) and ShowLeaderboardUI() also fail.

Everything works just fine when I push the apk to my testing device locally.

Here is the relevant adb logcat output:

```
.
.
.
.
07-24 15:08:47.682 8729 8775 W Unity : *** [Play Games Plugin 0.11.01] 07/24/22 15:08:46 +02:00 ERROR: Returning an error code.
07-24 15:08:47.682 8729 8775 W Unity : GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
.
.
.
07-24 15:08:47.850 8729 8775 I Unity : ProcessAuthentication failed
07-24 15:08:47.850 8729 8775 I Unity : GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()

.
.
.
.
07-24 15:08:47.682 8729 8775 W Unity : *** [Play Games Plugin 0.11.01] 07/24/22 15:08:46 +02:00 ERROR: Returning an error code.
07-24 15:08:47.682 8729 8775 W Unity : GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
.
.
.
07-24 15:08:47.850 8729 8775 I Unity : ProcessAuthentication failed
07-24 15:08:47.850 8729 8775 I Unity : GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
.
.
.
07-24 15:08:49.835 8729 8775 W Unity : Failed to submit highscore
07-24 15:08:49.835 8729 8775 W Unity : MainPlayer:FixedUpdate()
07-24 15:08:49.835 8729 8775 W Unity :
07-24 15:08:49.882 8729 8775 W Unity : *** [Play Games Plugin 0.11.01] 07/24/22 15:08:49 +02:00 ERROR: ReportScore can only be called after authentication.
07-24 15:08:49.882 8729 8775 W Unity : GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
.
.
.
07-24 15:08:55.450 8729 8775 I Unity : Trying to show Leaderboard UI now...
07-24 15:08:55.450 8729 8775 I Unity : GooglePlayGamesManager:ShowLeaderboardUI()
07-24 15:08:55.450 8729 8775 I Unity : UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
07-24 15:08:55.450 8729 8775 I Unity : UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
07-24 15:08:55.450 8729 8775 I Unity : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
07-24 15:08:55.450 8729 8775 I Unity : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
07-24 15:08:55.450 8729 8775 I Unity : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
07-24 15:08:55.450 8729 8775 I Unity :
07-24 15:08:55.454 8729 8775 W Unity : *** [Play Games Plugin 0.11.01] 07/24/22 15:08:55 +02:00 ERROR: ShowLeaderboardUI can only be called after authentication.
07-24 15:08:55.454 8729 8775 W Unity : GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
```

**Why are authentication and subsequent requests working when testing locally, but failing when distributing to beta testers? How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work.

Incase anyone else comes across **similar problems where the leaderboard is working locally but not in production**, maybe you forgot the same key configurations as I did.

**For **production**, you (obviously) need to**

1. **Publish** your OAuth screen

[image]

2. Make sure to **set up your credentials with the SHA-fingerprint of the **key Google uses to sign your app**** (not the fingerprint of the key you use to sign your app locally). You can get this fingerprint under **App Integrity** in the Google Play console.

[image]

3. Ensure that you are using the credential with just mentioned SHA-fingerprint in your leaderboard/achievement. This can be configured in the Google Play Console under **Play Game Services** -> **Setup and management** -> **Configuration**

[image]

These steps are "obviously" quite obvious, but I had skipped them.

For anyone looking for a full description on how to configure leaderboards in Google Play Console and Google Cloud, [James Brill](https://medium.com/@jebrill) wrote an excellent and detailed [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/setting-up-google-play-games-services-for-your-unity-android-game-64814f8353c7), which, as of my writing of this answer works if followed precisely!